# Hide and seek game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

$A$ and $B$ go to the Senate to play a game of Hide-and-Seek. There are $100$ rooms in the Senate, and $B$ picks one of them and hides there till the game ends.

$A$, at the beginning of every turn, picks one room and searches in it. Since he is human and thus fallible, he only has a $60\%$ chance of finding $B$ if she is in fact hiding in the room. If he fails to find her in the room, $B$'s score increases by one, and the next turn starts, whereupon $A$ must pick another room to check (he can also check the same room again). $B$ remains in the room she initially chose.

Given that $A$ and $B$ play with perfect strategies, what is the expected value of $B$'s score at the end of the game?

I tried with $1$ room. There is only one hiding place for $B$. So the expected score of $$B = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0.4^{n-1}0.6(n-1)=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: What have you tried?  100 sounds like a large number...what about 1? Then 2, 3... at least get a feel for the calculation.

Comment: The calculation for 1 room looks perfect.  For 2 rooms, though, this method looks hard .... there are a lot of possible "search paths".  I'll write out a different approach and post it below.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is better off searching a new room rather than an old room.
Suppose $A$ searched all hundred rooms (even after finding $B$).
They have a $3/5$ chance of finding $B$ during this sweep, and if they
do it is after searching $50.5$ rooms on average.  So 
$$E=\frac35(49.5)+\frac25(100+E)\\
\frac35E=29.7+40\\
E=116\frac16$$

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is not being accepted at https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/81

Comment: Is the answer $\dfrac{703}{6}$ or 117.2 to 1 dp ?

Comment: No, the answer is not $\frac{703}{6}$. You can verify yourself at https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/81

Comment: @guest123456: do you know the expected answer at that site is correct?  Note that nobody has solved it.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan , no I don't know the answer. I think that the answer of that site may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  This solves a different problem.  In this calculation it is assumed that A searches randomly.  That is sub-optimal.  It is clearly better to go through all the rooms before repeating. Perhaps the calculation still has some value so I'll leave it up.

Let E be the expected score (= Expected number of rooms searched - 1).  Look at the first search, it can have one of three (mutually exclusive) outcomes:

Outcome A:  A finds B!  Probability = $\frac {1}{100} \frac{3}{5}$ And in this case E is 0.

Outcome B:  A looks in the right room but fails to find B.  Probability = $\frac {1}{100} \frac{2}{5}$ And in this case E goes to E + 1.

Outcome C: A looks in the wrong room.  Probability = $\frac {99}{100}$ And in this case E also goes to E + 1.

Combining these, we get $$E = \frac {1}{100} \frac{3}{5} (0) \;\;+\;\;\frac {1}{100} \frac{2}{5} (E + 1) + \frac {99}{100} (E + 1) $$ This is easily solved to yield $E= \frac{497}{3}$

Comment: This answer is not correct. :( This approach also gives wrong answer for $1$ room. $E=\frac{1}{1}\frac{3}{5}(0)+\frac{1}{1}\frac{2}{5}(E+1)+\frac{0}{1}(E+1)$, this gives $E=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: I believe $\frac 23 $ is correct for 1 room...should have said, in your calculation you seem to give B a point if she is found on the first search, but the rules say that this is no score...hence you are off by 1.

Comment: To be precise:  in your method, if B is found on the $n^{th}$ search the contribution you want should be $.4^{n-1}.6 (n-1)$.

Comment: I submitted your answer at https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/81 It is showing wrong answer.

Comment: Are you seeing the correct answer as $\frac {500}{3}$ ?  If so, That would suggest that you meant to award B a point even for the search she is discovered during.

Comment: Neither $\frac{500}{3}$ nor $\frac{497}{3}$ is correct answer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I am assuming that A chooses randomly.  That is slightly suboptimal.  Having looked in room 1 and found nothing, it is wiser to try another room...not repeating until you have covered all rooms once.  I'll revisit (but it may take a while).

Comment: Yeah, $A$ and $B$ plays with perfect strategy. So choices are not random. I missed that point too.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include that the answer must be accurate to .1 decimal.

I believe you are over complicating the question. There are 100 possible rooms for player B to hide in. You are trying to find the odds of not only player A locating player B, but also with the factor that player A only has a 60% chance of finding player B, if in fact they have chosen the correct room.

Based on the question, they are playing "A" game of hide and seek, thus meaning one game.

The odds of player A finding player B in 100 rooms with only an expected accuracy of locating player B in the correct room of 60%, would mean that player B has the odds of obtaining a score of 166.7 if you are rounding up.

If you choose to not round up, then it would be 166.6, or more accurately 166.666667

Simply 100 rooms divided by 60% accuracy.

**Edit** tried it out and was not the correct answer, sorry but now this is bugging me. Interested in what it is.

Comment: Has anyone been able to make any progress on this answer?

Comment: I believe there is some variant we are not taking into account, reminds me of the Monty Hall Problem, game theory and probability theory. Could it be the increased odds of player A, in each new turn of searching for player B, in actually locating player B?